# Keras deep learning sentiment analysis - supervised or unsupervised

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, text-classification

I am a bit confused because about the topic deep learning.

My question: Let's assume that we've got a task to solve. Reviews should be classified where they are positive or negative by usage of Keras deep learning model.

Now: Does this task belong to supervised or unsupervised learning? Why? And how does deep learning and neural network work here? How do they learn? Isn't it better, if a machine learning algorithm is being used for this task?

Comment: Unsupervised or Supervised depends on the availability of labels, your task description does not mention anything related to that.

Comment: A neural network is one example of a machine learning algorithm. Usually movie review classification algorithms are trained on a labeled dataset, so they fall under the category of supervised learning.

Comment: Hi guys.

So I've got a labeld dataset. If I want to classify them by the usage of Keras neuronal networks - is it then called neuronal network classification? Or how is it called?

Answer (score 1):

Supervised learning is the machine learning task of learning a function that maps an input to an output based on example input-output pairs. It infers a function from labeled training data consisting of a set of training examples. In supervised learning, each example is a pair consisting of an input object (typically a vector) and a desired output value (also called the supervisory signal). A supervised learning algorithm analyzes the training data and produces an inferred function, which can be used for mapping new examples.

Unsupervised learning is a type of machine learning algorithm used to draw inferences from datasets consisting of input data without labeled responses. The most common unsupervised learning method is cluster analysis, which is used for exploratory data analysis to find hidden patterns or grouping in data.

(Definitions from wikipedia and mathworks)

There are already labeled datasets (with the actual reviews for each input) for the task you mentioned, hence you can always model it as a supervised learning problem and use a machine learning model such as SVM, Random Forest, or MLP to solve the task.

https://www.kaggle.com/c/sentiment-analysis-on-movie-reviews/data

https://www.kaggle.com/snap/amazon-fine-food-reviews

https://www.kaggle.com/jessicali9530/kuc-hackathon-winter-2018

https://www.kaggle.com/nicapotato/womens-ecommerce-clothing-reviews

https://www.kaggle.com/utathya/imdb-review-dataset

https://www.kaggle.com/datafiniti/hotel-reviews

https://www.kaggle.com/sid321axn/amazon-alexa-reviews

https://www.kaggle.com/bittlingmayer/amazonreviews

https://www.kaggle.com/lakshmi25npathi/imdb-dataset-of-50k-movie-reviews

Comment: Thank you for your kind response! But how can I justify solving this issue by using an neuronal network (keras) ? 

It's a part of my thesis and I need to use Keras for solving this problem. So my essay must have an explanation why I've solved this isse by the usage of neuronal networkds (altough it might be solvable by using the above mentiond machine learning models)

Comment: I think that would be a different kind of question, for that you should have given the dataset sample, tokenizer, and then could have asked for a suitable model.